# Writing the data received from a Post request to a text file saved in the Server (ASP, C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, client-server

I am currently using ASP and C#.
In my project I used a POST method to pass information from a page to another.
On this page I receive a string value that looks like the following:

```
"["Fruit:Apple","Animal:Dog", Food:Pizza"]"
```

It's a single long string that looks like an array. I want now to write this string to a `.txt` file that is saved in my server.

My question is how can I do this? Will I be able to write it using C# or do I have to use something else since the file is in server?

Could you please share with me an idea/sample code to get this done? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use  System I.O `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt", text);`